# HP Pavilion Laptop Overheating

Tags: 12.04, overheating, hp-pavilion

I'm using Wubi (12.04.2 LTS) to dual-boot between Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but when I boot up Ubuntu my laptop overheats and after some hours (sometimes minutes) it shutdowns because of the overheat.

I tried installing Additional Drivers but when I opened it up it said that there were no drivers.

Is there a way to fix this?

Specs:

CPU - AMD Phenom(tm) II N660 Dual-Core Processor

GPU - AMD Radeon HD 6470M (w/ switchable graphics)

Comment: some solutions: install addtional driver from ati website. check this link for how to http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx and install `jupiter` or google : How to solve over heat problem Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Skymaster,

This should really be a comment not answer... but I don't yet have enough rep to add a comment !

So in [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) on the Ubuntu Wiki there are instructions for installing and using the various sensors with Ubuntu. This should enable you to get more info as to what exactly is causing the overheating. Other than that, you could test on a live CD to see if you still have the same problem (it may be a WUBI specific issue that needs a bug report).

In fact a hunt and I found [this](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/29465/) page  on ubuntu brainstorm, and lead me to the launchpad bug report

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/370173
```

You should add your info to the report, or open a new bug if you think it is different enough.

Did I mention that I don't have enough reputation to post comments or links !

The thread also has some workaround details.

If you are a linux newb and need more help, just put a comment into this thread (or better still update your question).

Also I would highly recomend the ubuntu forums (if you are already a member), although I get the impression that a lot of the forums folks hand around here also.

sorry I feel that I haven't really helped out much - its a bit of a naff answer, keep us updated with how things are going...

David.

Answer (score 0):

I had heating problems too(and my battery was drained too), and then I found out about Jupiter.

This is a simple program with which you can select power modes, I simply put it on power on demand, and now I am using my laptop to cool my drinks.

> Installation:
>
> open terminal and do this.
>
> add the repository
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`
>
> update
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> install jupiter
>
> `sudo apt-get install jupiter`
>
> and to other people reading this and are
>   using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell
>
> `sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee`

Have a nice day :)